# Traceback (most recent call last) pandas and expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

i'm working on a machine learning project of resume screening and i'm beginner with Pandas and Python. In cleaning dataset phase i used the script below and it worked on the original dataframe but not mine. So i tried to solve this error by myself, but i couldn't. So if someone can help me, i will be thankful.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
cols = ['Resume_title','City','State','Description','work_experiences','Educations','Skills','Links','Certificates','Additional information']
resumeDataSet = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\A\A\resume_data.csv", header=None, names=cols)
# above line will be different depending on where you saved your data, and your file name
resumeDataSet['cleaned_resume'] = ''
resumeDataSet.head()
```

The block where i get the error :

```
import re
def cleanResume(resumeText):
    resumeText = re.sub('http\S+\s*', ' ', resumeText)  # remove URLs
    resumeText = re.sub('RT|cc', ' ', resumeText)  # remove RT and cc
    resumeText = re.sub('#\S+', '', resumeText)  # remove hashtags
    resumeText = re.sub('@\S+', '  ', resumeText)  # remove mentions
    resumeText = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape("""!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"""), ' ', resumeText)  # remove punctuations
    resumeText = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r' ', resumeText) 
    resumeText = re.sub('\s+', ' ', resumeText)  # remove extra whitespace
    return resumeText
    

resumeDataSet['cleaned_resume'] = resumeDataSet.Educations.apply(lambda x: cleanResume(x))
```

the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-cfdba0f1a095> in <module>
     11 
     12 
---> 13 resumeDataSet['cleaned_resume'] = resumeDataSet.Educations.apply(lambda x: cleanResume(x))

G:\Anaconda\envs\Pandas\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4136             else:
   4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4139 
   4140         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-16-cfdba0f1a095> in <lambda>(x)
     11 
     12 
---> 13 resumeDataSet['cleaned_resume'] = resumeDataSet.Educations.apply(lambda x: cleanResume(x))

<ipython-input-16-cfdba0f1a095> in cleanResume(resumeText)
      1 import re
      2 def cleanResume(resumeText):
----> 3     resumeText = re.sub('http\S+\s*', ' ', resumeText)  # remove URLs
      4     resumeText = re.sub('RT|cc', ' ', resumeText)  # remove RT and cc
      5     resumeText = re.sub('#\S+', '', resumeText)  # remove hashtags

G:\Anaconda\envs\Pandas\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    208     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    209     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 210     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    211 
    212 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string escapes are processed in the url string so to avoid that use raw strings, replace the pattern in the re.sub with raw strings

```
import re
def cleanResume(resumeText):
    resumeText = str(resumeText)
    resumeText = re.sub(r'http\S+\s*', r' ', resumeText)  # remove URLs
    resumeText = re.sub(r'RT|cc', r' ', resumeText)  # remove RT and cc
    resumeText = re.sub(r'#\S+', r'', resumeText)  # remove hashtags
    resumeText = re.sub(r'@\S+', r'  ', resumeText)  # remove mentions
    resumeText = re.sub(r'[%s]' % re.escape("""!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"""), r' ', resumeText)  # remove punctuations
    resumeText = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r' ', resumeText) 
    resumeText = re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', resumeText)  # remove extra whitespace
    return resumeText
    

resumeDataSet['cleaned_resume'] = resumeDataSet.Educations.apply(lambda x: cleanResume(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it's still the same error even when i change it.

Comment: thank you for yor effort to help me but the error remain the same.

Comment: change resumeText to strings before passing it to re.sub

Comment: thank you so much it worked thank you !! Can you please explain me what caused the error and why you changed it to  string to work and the thing in url line if possible and another time thank you.